# Adobe Air truncate Image's url automatically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, flex4.5

I am loading image from "alsdfkj.cloudfront.net" and my image contain special character like # in its file name. now see Charles's snapshot of request and response which i have attached in the post, you can see that #2.jpg is missing from URL. if i write this URL in browser then it works. then what is the problem to ADOBE AIR have ?

`alsdfkj.cloudfront.net` is dummy Domain to ask Question so Please do not try to open it

list of Reference:

1. `http://alsdfkj.cloudfront.net/users/2/VisualizationModule/thumb/Photo on 9-1-12 at 6.59 PM #2.jpg`
2. [image: Charles Request and Response]

Thanks,
JK Patel

Comment: I would recommend using escape() on the String of your URL and load the escaped URL

Comment: Well just use url encode in order to load weird urls..

Comment: @Andrey Popov Thanks For Replay, i use `image.source = encodeURI(value as String);` but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @CreativeMagic thanks for reply, image.source = escape(value as String); also t didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I used trick to solve this issue, I have changed each and every uploaded file to timestamp and then I access it by XXXXXXXXXXXXX.jpg instead of its original name. 
this is not a permanent solution but I have to use this trick to solve this issue temporary. if you have anyother Solution then most welcome.

Thanks
JK Patel